# Change the owner of a MySQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, ownership

The [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-procedure.html) says that I can print the code used to define a stored procedure using `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE`, but apparently that only works if you a) have select permissions on the `mysql.proc` table, or b) own the procedure.

The database in question was maintained by a co-worker who's moved on, so I *should* be the owner of all the stuff that used to be "his".  The only problem is, I can't seem to find any documentation on how to change the owner *in the database* -- most of the Google hits point to how to change *file* ownership (which of course is a basic, generic sysadmin task).

One place pointed to `sp_changeobjectownership` but it looks like they might have accidentally been trying to use a MS SQL Server sproc instead.  Is there any simple way to say "change all the objects in [database] owned by [user1] to be owned by [user2]"?  Failing that, I'll take a command to change the owner of a single object...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a column `definer` in `mysql.proc` table and a row for each stored procedure or function that can be updated to your login.

Comment: Works for me, but please don't forget to restart the data base, in my case it was necesary at MySQL 5.7. Greetings from stackOverFlow in spanish!